# Как разделить отсортированный список на много списков с одинаковыми элементами?

Tags: python

Как разделить отсортированный список на много списков с одинаковыми элементами?

`[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4] -> [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [4]]`

Comment: а как бы вы делали это на бумажке?

Comment: @MBo можно сделать императивным способом, сохраняя текущий элемент и добавляя в новый подсписок элементы, пока они повторяются, иначе обновить текущий элемент. Но верю, что тут есть элегантное решение (функциональное)

Comment: from itertools import groupby

Comment: можно решить через словарь

Comment: @MBo спасибо, вспомнил